# Assign points in a text file to be x and y in a list

Tags: python

I have a text file that has data of x , y like this:

```
-10.61118889    2.28427887
-13.31124592    8.48367596
-13.66134357    8.83389187
-12.8115654 1.28432655
-11.71096611    6.03327417
-12.76088619    5.83374786
-14.01123905    8.38309383
-14.71052933    8.78343105
-12.61050415    9.18339539
```

I want to create a list that reads each line and assigns the first no. as x and the second as y, something like this:

```
[(-10.61118889,2.28427887),(-13.31124592,8.48367596) ....]
```

I have tried this but it didn't work as it has constructed a table with header x and y:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('convex_hull_points.txt', sep=' ')
df.to_csv('convex_hull_points.csv', index=False)
data = pd.read_csv('convex_hull_points.csv', sep=' ',  header=None, names=['X','Y'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the OP thinks pandas is necessary for this. To produce a list of tuples as shown in the question:

```
list_ = []

with open('convex_hull_points.txt') as chp:
  for line in chp:
    x, y = line.split()
    list_.append((float(x), float(y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehensions` like this :

```
with open('convex_hull_points.txt') as f:
    data = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
    out = [(float(k), float(v)) for k, v in data]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[(-10.61118889, 2.28427887), (-13.31124592, 8.48367596), (-13.66134357, 8.83389187), (-12.8115654, 1.28432655), (-11.71096611, 6.03327417), (-12.76088619, 5.83374786), (-14.01123905, 8.38309383), (-14.71052933, 8.78343105), (-12.61050415, 9.18339539)]
```